# Flex, how to exchange user names and peer IDs between all connected users

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, stream, chat, p2p

Hello I'm building a chat using Flex. The problem is how to do that new user get the list off all users online and added to the lists of all users. I try to put this information in DataGrid through dataProvider "callerns":

```
<s:DataGrid x="10" y="125" width="238" height="125" alternatingRowColors="[ #67676767, #555555]"
            borderVisible="true" chromeColor="#555555" color="#CCCCCC"
            contentBackgroundColor="#555555" dataProvider="{callerns}" fontWeight="bold"
            requestedRowCount="4" rollOverColor="#08700D" selectionColor="#08700D"
            symbolColor="#CCCCCC">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="name" headerText="USER ONLINE"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="peerID" headerText="USER ID"></s:GridColumn>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Here is the part of code:

```
 [Bindable]
  private var callerns:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
```

...........

```
private function netStatusEvent(event:NetStatusEvent):void{

            trace('NetConnection status event (1): ' + event.info.code);

            //writeText(event.info.code);

            switch(event.info.code){
                case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                    log('Connected (NearID: '+nc.nearID+')', 'debug');
                    log('Connection sucsessful');

                    MyPeerID = nc.nearID;
                    txtFingerprint.text = MyPeerID;
                    initSendNetStream();
                    callerns.addItem({peerID: MyPeerID, name: myName});
                    setupGroup();                       
                    break;

                case "NetGroup.Posting.Notify":
                    receiveMessage(event.info.message);
                    log('Message posted');
                    break;

                case "NetGroup.Connect.Success":
                    log('Net Group connection sucsessful');
                    connected = true;
                    break;

                case 'NetStream.Connect.Success':
                    log('Peer Connected (FarID: '+event.info.stream.farID+')', 'debug');
                    break;

                case "NetGroup.Neighbor.Connect":
                    log('New user connected');
                    break;

            }

        }  

private function initSendNetStream():void{
            trace("initSendStream");

            sendStream = new NetStream(nc,NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
            sendStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusEvent);
            var clientObject:Object = new Object();
            clientObject.onPeerConnect = function(callerns:NetStream):Boolean{

                initRecvStream(callerns.farID);
                callerns.send('onPeerNameUpdate', MyPeerID, myName);

                return true;
            }

            sendStream.client = clientObject;
            sendStream.publish('video');
            log('Net Stream publish start');

        }   

        private function initRecvStream(peerID:String):void {
            //log('initRecvStream', 'debug');

            var stream:NetStream = new NetStream(nc, peerID);
            stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusEvent);
            stream.play('video');

            var client:Object = new Object();
            client.onPeerNameUpdate = onPeerNameUpdate;

            stream.client = client;

            var peer:Object = new Object();
            peer.stream = stream;

            recvStreams[peerID] = peer;
        }

        private function onPeerNameUpdate(peerID:String, name:String):void {
            //log('onPeerNameUpdate received: '+peerID+':'+name, 'debug');
            //log(name+' connected to your channel', 'debug');
            callerns.addItem({peerID: peerID, name: name});
        }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and new users aren't added to the grid. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What kind of service are you using for randezvous? And what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I'm using Cirrus. Basically I solve my task. I've done it through NetGroup opportunities. Also it may be done as mentioned here: http://blog.leeburrows.com/2011/11/p2p-flash-on-a-local-network-part-2/ but it's suitable only for peerID, maybe you now how to use this method for user names also? Thank you for answer!

Answer (score 0):

Removed original post seems I'm wrong, this works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group creationComplete="group1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
         height="100%"
         width="100%"
         xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var callerns : ArrayCollection;

            protected function group1_creationCompleteHandler(event : FlexEvent) : void
            {
                callerns = new ArrayCollection();
            }

            protected function addItemClickHandler(event : MouseEvent) : void
            {
                callerns.addItem({peerID: "somePeerID", name: "someName"});
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Button click="addItemClickHandler(event)"
              label="Add Item"/>
    <s:Button click="propertyChangeClickHandler(event)"
              label="Dispatch Property Change"/>
    <s:DataGrid alternatingRowColors="[ #67676767, #555555]"
                borderVisible="true"
                chromeColor="#555555"
                color="#CCCCCC"
                contentBackgroundColor="#555555"
                dataProvider="{callerns}"
                fontWeight="bold"
                height="125"
                requestedRowCount="4"
                rollOverColor="#08700D"
                selectionColor="#08700D"
                symbolColor="#CCCCCC"
                width="238"
                x="10"
                y="125">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="name"
                              headerText="USER ONLINE">
                </s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="peerID"
                              headerText="USER ID">
                </s:GridColumn>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:columns>
    </s:DataGrid>
</s:Group>
```

So I was originally wrong, hitting the button does cause an update to the grid. It would have been extremely helpful if you had posted a link to the original tutorial you were building off of, I found it and got it working with spark just fine.  I'm assuming you got this part figured out already but here's the basic chat client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application minHeight="600"
               minWidth="955"
               xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private const SERVER_ADDRESS : String = "rtmfp://p2p.rtmfp.net/";
            private const DEVELOPER_KEY: String = PUT_YOUR_DEV_KEY_HERE;

            private var nc : NetConnection;
            private var myPeerID : String;
            private var farPeerID : String;
            // streams
            private var sendStream : NetStream;
            private var recvStream : NetStream;

            private function initConnection() : void
            {
                if (txtFingerprint.text)
                {
                    farPeerID = txtFingerprint.text;
                }

                nc = new NetConnection();
                nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, ncStatus);
                nc.connect(SERVER_ADDRESS + DEVELOPER_KEY);
            }

            private function ncStatus(event : NetStatusEvent) : void
            {
                trace(event.info.code);

                myPeerID = nc.nearID;

                txtFingerprint.text = myPeerID;
            }

            private function initSendStream() : void
            {
                trace("initSendStream");

                sendStream = new NetStream(nc, NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS);
                sendStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
                sendStream.publish("media");

                var sendStreamClient : Object = new Object();
                sendStreamClient.onPeerConnect = function(callerns : NetStream) : Boolean
                {

                    farPeerID = callerns.farID;

                    trace("onPeerConnect " + farPeerID);

                    return true;
                }

                sendStream.client = sendStreamClient;

            }

            private function initRecvStream() : void
            {
                recvStream = new NetStream(nc, farPeerID);
                recvStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
                recvStream.play("media");

                recvStream.client = this;
            }

            public function receiveSomeData(str : String) : void
            {
                txtReceiveData.text = str;
            }

            private function sendSomeData() : void
            {
                sendStream.send("receiveSomeData", txtSendData.text);
            }

            private function netStatusHandler(event : NetStatusEvent) : void
            {
                trace(event.info.code);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:TextInput id="txtFingerprint"
                  width="391"
                  x="10"
                  y="10"/>
    <mx:Button click="initConnection()"
               label="Connect"
               x="409"
               y="10"/>
    <mx:TextInput id="txtSendData"
                  x="10"
                  y="40"/>
    <mx:TextInput id="txtReceiveData"
                  width="251"
                  x="10"
                  y="70"/>
    <mx:Button click="sendSomeData()"
               label="Send data"
               x="178"
               y="40"/>
    <mx:Button click="initSendStream()"
               label="initSendStream"
               x="10"
               y="100"/>
    <mx:Button click="initRecvStream();"
               label="initReceiveStream"
               x="132"
               y="100"/>
    <mx:Text height="122"
             text="Hint: First running Flash app - click Connect to get Fingerprint PeerID. Copy and paste this PeerID to second running Flash app to the same field and click Connect. Then initSendStream and initReceiveStream on both of them and finally you can write some text and click Send data."
             width="391"
             x="10"
             y="130"/>

</s:Application>
```

Get a developer key here:

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=cirrus

I'm not sure what's going wrong but as the commenter above says you need to include how exactly it's breaking, that is what happens when you debug (be sure to install the debug flash player for whatever browser your using, beware chrome manages it's own plugin by default) what do you see in the console, do you get any errors etc.  The tutorial app works fine for me, having this deal with two way communication and maintaining a list of all connected peers seems to be the goal correct?  I also don't understand the question about NetGroup, there's more on P2P that covers that here though:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/p2p_rtmfp_groups.html

I wish you would have included more information about where you started and where you're headed with all this though (and code, I always want more code :)

Comment: Thank you for answer!  I've done it through NetGroup opportunities. what do you mean under temporary collection? Could it be done without using netGroup?